# Fast unanchored text search for an array

Tags: arrays, string, algorithm

The input: An array of strings, and a single string.

The task: Find all entries in the array where any substring of the entry matches the input string.

The input array can be prepared or sorted in any way required, and any auxiliary data structure required built. The time required to prepare the data structures is (within bounds of sanity) unimportant.

The goal is maximum speed on the search.

What algorithm would you use that isn't just a linear search?

Answer (score 0):

Because it says time required to prepare data structures is unimportant, I'd hash it. The key is a string (specifically, a substring), and the value is a list of integers corresponding to indices in the array whose elements have the key as a substring.

To build, take each string in the array and determine all possible substrings of that string, inserting each such key-value pair into the hash table. If the key already exists, append the index to the list rather than inserting/creating a new list.

Once you build this hash table, it's as easy as O(1) grab the list based on the input string and return.

**EDIT**: Looking more closely at the question, it seems like you'd want to return the actual *strings* in the array, rather than their indices. The hash table approach will work either way.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to build an index of all string suffixes. Look into [suffix trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) to find out how this could be done. Wikipedia article might be too generalized so here is an adapted algoritm:

**Building index**

- for each string in array

  - get all its suffixes (there N suffixes for a string of length N) and store a reference to a string in an ordered associative container (OrderedMap> (index)

**Searching**

- find an lower bound of your search term in index
- move over an index starting from lower bound until index key won't stop being prefixed with the search term
- a sum of all references you will find is your search result

There is N²/2 substrings for a string of length N but only N suffixes. So suffix based data-structure should be more memory effective that substring based.